# Numberpicker: Play sound on scroll

Tags: android

I have a numberpicker like below.

```
<NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

How can I add a short clicking sound when I scroll the numberpicker?
In IOS, the click sound is standard. Is there something like that in android too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.OnScrollListener.html and have the app play a sound when it is triggered.

Edit:
Yes, you can also use the OnValueChangedListener if you want a sound to play each time the value is changed.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I want to play a click sound always when a new value appears. When i fast fling for example 5 values are getting skipped without playing a sound. Thats not cool.

Comment: us OnValueChangedListener instead.

Comment: Your link does solve the problem, but it doesn't provide the user very much context if the link changes. Is it possible for you to expand on this answer and add an excerpt of the code on the other side of the link?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyActivity extends AppcompatActivity{

MediaPlayer mp ;
NumberPicker myPicker;
...

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
...
myPicker = findByViewId(R.id.my_picker);
myPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(this::changeValue);
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.my_tick_sound);
....


}

 private void changeValue(NumberPicker numberPicker, int i, int i1){
 
 if(mp != null){

 if(mp.isPlaying) mp.stop();

 mp.start();


 


}
//do logic.....//

}
```

I hope help for you...